# Database Decimal data type is equivalent to what java data type?

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate

I am using hibernate to create the mapping between database data model and java entity classes. In the data model diagram I have:

```
 trans_id:Decimal
```

What java data type Decimal would map to?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: BigDecimal, as that is precise, i.o. double. BigDeimal is a (COBOL) pain to work with, but superior to double.

Comment: It depends on the needed precision. BigDecimal is the one if you want to get the thing well done. Double also does the work if you don't need a very high precision.

Comment: @Averroes inb4 doubledouble datatype

Comment: I am using Oracle as my database.

Comment: @Cruncher inb4 quadruple